# Looking for the name of a comic series about two wandering brothers

Tags: story-identification, comics

In my childhood I read a short series of comics about;

- Two young brothers, forced to wander around wartime Europe(?) because they had no papers/identification.
- Common themes were difficulties with the authorities, and constantly having to flee or move on,
- The story stayed light-hearted and humorous, with the brothers typically prevailing against their oppressors,
- The style was similar to an Asterix or Tintin comic, possibly a French or Belgian artist?
- I think there were at least four books - not sure if more existed.

Some plot points or scenes I remember;

- They'd **had** a home with a big workshop, but were forced to leave,
- The older brother was an inventor, who built many solutions to their problems,
- At the end of each book they'd often have to flee offscreen to escape an angry crowd;

  - In one book they built a surprise hot air balloon and flew away,
  - In one book they followed a series of tunnels deeper and deeper underground,
  - In one book they built a few steps, then kept dismantling and rebuilding each step higher until they were high in the sky. (floating somehow?)
- At one point they had to go around a fortified country border extending out into the ocean.
- At one point they were stuck *between* two countries, about to go to war over a broken bridge - the elder brother fixed the bridge and moved on.
- At one point they were so sick of the bureaucrats denying them access or requiring papers they didn't have, that they built a 'fence making machine' that built tidy wrought iron fences around every government building.

I have *NO* idea of the name of the series or the author. I read it probably in the early to mid 1990s.

Comment: Were there any science fiction or fantasy elements to this?

Comment: It was fantasy - I don't think any of the countries they visited were "real". I remember that the machines they built were fairly eclectic/steampunk, and the floating steps in the sky bit was never really explained.
*(If I remembered enough to categorise it perfectly, maybe I wouldn't even be asking this question)* If there's a more suitable SE site, I'm happy to move the question there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of this sounds like [The House that Beebo built](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0224010913), written by y Janine Ast & Alain Gree, illustrated by Philippe Fix. I've only read this one but I believe there is at least one other story.  (Also I haven't read it for a while, so my memory may be fuzzy!)

Beebo inherits an old house which is neglected and overgrown. He and his friend Mop fix it up. One room is a large glass bubble where Mop blows bubbles out, there is a wooden staircase/bookcase inside. The city council decides to tear it down, (possibly for a new road?). One night Beebo and Mop refit a mechanical digger up as a dragon and scare the workers off so the council sends the police and fire department. They retreat up the house till they run out of room. Beebo builds 5-6 wooden stairs, sets them in the air and the pair climb aboard. They pull the last step up, continue the process and climb their way into the sky.

I don't remember if Beebo and Mop's relationship was stated - Mop looks young but I don't think they were father and son.

I would say this question fits here as this is a fantasy book.

edit:  found a lovely picture:
 [image]

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much! ...WOW are they expensive.